# Random variables with transformed discrete distributions cannot be applied to Probability[] function?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, bugs

I have two discrete uniform distributions over same support:

```
Dx = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{-8, 8}];  
Dy = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{-8, 8}];
```

I use random variables X $\sim$ Dx, Y $\sim$ Dy to model condition in some if-else clause in C code.
For example,

```
if (3 * x + 1 > y) {
   ... 
}
```

So, I model this condition by random event 3*X + 1 > Y.
Then probability I look for is:

```
Probability[
  x > y, 
  {Distributed[x, TransformedDistribution[3 * x + 1, Distributed[x, Dx]]],
   Distributed[y, Dy]}
]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica produces nothing.
As for me, this is very strange behavior because Mathematica also cannot compute mean for the product distribution of {X, Y}.
Maybe, this problem is caused by different support of X and Y.

How can I compute this probability?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following computes the probability you asked for, but I'm at a loss to understand why your notation won't work. It seems correct to me.

```
Probability[
 3 x + 1 > y, {Distributed[x, Dx], Distributed[y, Dy]}]

(*
==> 147/289
*)
```

The Probability / Distribution functions are quite young and hence not fully bulletproofed and I have encountered a number of bugs myself. I suppose/hope that in the next release they will be solved. I suggest you contact Wolfram support (support@wolfram.com). But perhaps someone else here may find out what's wrong.

A few of mine:

No random variates from PDFs that stem from multivariate distributions:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
   PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 0]][{x, 
     y}], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}];
RandomVariate[dist]
```

This works for 3, but not for 5 (and higher):

```
Expectation[x,x\[Distributed] OrderDistribution[{GeometricDistribution[0.1], 3}, 3]]
Expectation[x,x\[Distributed] OrderDistribution[{GeometricDistribution[0.1], 5}, 5]]
```

The following crashes the kernel after a minute or so (so, **DO NOT EXECUTE**):

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[Sin[u], u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]], 0]
```