# NExpectation behaves oddly with EmpiricalDistribution

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, version-8

Note: this is fixed in version 9.

---

My question concerns the usage of `NExpectation` and `Expectation` and why I see the behavior I see in the following example.

First take some data and derive an `EmpiricalDistribution`:

```
data = {4, 104, 96, 80, 22, 76, 106, 18, 98, 44, 112, 78, 50, 120, 2, 6, 
        100, 10, 68, 80, 42, 66, 100, 58, 4, 76, 18, 102, 6, 16, 52, 32, 62, 
        36, 18, 4, 54, 98, 38, 74, 16, 22, 102, 2, 2, 4, 22, 72, 100, 82, 48, 
        16, 34, 44, 130, 50, 48, 74, 60, 96, 8, 118, 30, 58, 84, 4, 70, 66, 
        40, 14, 92, 68, 42, 56, 56, 16, 40, 12, 22, 26, 98, 4, 80, 100, 36, 
        88, 48, 26, 28, 94, 22, 26, 78, 16, 52, 8, 10, 2};

dist = EmpiricalDistribution[data];
```

You can plot `PDF`s and `CDF`s of the distribution:

```
Row[{DiscretePlot[PDF[dist, x], {x, data}, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 300], 
     DiscretePlot[CDF[dist, x], {x, 0, Max@data, 1}, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

They look like this:

[image: PDF & CDF plots]

That covers the background.  Now execute the following and it gets a little odd:

```
Expectation[X \[Conditioned] X > 4, X \[Distributed] dist]
NExpectation[X \[Conditioned] X > 4, X \[Distributed] dist]
N[Expectation[X \[Conditioned] X > 4, X \[Distributed] dist]]

620/11
NExpectation[X \[Conditioned] X > 4, X \[Distributed]DataDistribution[<<"Empirical">>, {51}]]
56.3636
```

So, what gives?

How come `NExpectation[...]` doesn't calculate an answer, but `N[Expectation[...]]` does?  Clearly, `Expectation` handles `EmpiricalDistribution` without a problem.  One would think that `NExpectation` would as well.  Doesn't this seem odd? Just hoping that understanding why Mathematica does this might yield additional insights into Mathematica itself.

Comment: That is weird. I think it might be a bug, because using `HistogramDistribution` works as expected in all 3 cases.

Comment: I guess you may add this to my [Distributions bug list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4290/57).

Comment: I wonder if somehow the equivalent of a tag set for NExpectation with EmpiricalDistribution got overlooked in its definition.

Comment: @Jagra Look at the `TracePrint` of `NExpectation`. For a kernel function it's extremely verbose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't perhaps exactly what you are looking for but here are some points worth noting.

In version 8 `NExpectation` uses numerical integration and summation methods whereas `N[Expectation[...]]` uses direct integration or summation and then approximates numerically after the fact.

Though the idea is for data-distributions in M to behave just like regular distributions they are very different creatures under the hood. `EmpiricalDistribution` is perhaps the most different in that it is hard to categorize as discrete or continuous (whereas something like `HistogramDistribution` or `SmoothKernelDistribution` is continuous).

Taking both of these into consideration, general `NExpectation` methods won't work for `EmpiricalDistribution` directly out of the box.
Expectations for `EmpiricalDistribution` are computed in the same way as those for raw lists of data.  For example...

```
Expectation[f[x], x \[Distributed] Range[10]] == Expectation[f[x], 
   x \[Distributed]EmpiricalDistribution[Range[10]]]

==> True
```

This is effectively accomplished by simply mapping the function `f` over the list and taking the mean.

In my opinion there isn't a very good reason not to have a special case for `NExpectation[EmpiricalDistribution[...]]` that is effectively `N[Expectation[EmpiricalDistribution[...]]]`. It just isn't there in 8.